# yii2 codeception wont create coverage report

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I have a fresh install of yii2 and I have enabled coverage in /codeception.yml but neither xml or html code coverage reports are generating.

If I run testing from frontend folder, the coverage is getting generated. If I run from project root, it is not.

I am using `--coverage --coverage-xml` All my tests are failing but that is all right. The coverage report should get generated even if 0%.

This is the frontend codeception yml

```
namespace: frontend\tests
actor_suffix: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
coverage:
    enabled: true
    include:
        - controllers/*
        - components/*
        - urlrules/*
        - models/*
        - views/*
        - ../common/
    remote: true
    low_limit: 30
    high_limit: 60
modules:
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: 'config/test-local.php'
```

And this is the root/global yml

```
# global codeception file to run tests from all apps
include:
    - common
    - frontend
    - backend
paths:
    log: console/runtime/logs
settings:
    colors: true
coverage:
    enabled: true
    include:
        - common/*
        - console/*
        - frontend/*
        - backend/*
    low_limit: 30
    high_limit: 60
```

Comment: are you doing solely unit tests, or are you doing functional/acceptance tests also? What happens when you run `codecept run unit --coverage-html` ?

Comment: the default install has functional tests too. from root dir, it is not generating any reports. only when I run from frontend dir, does it generate correctly. I am wondering how the config files are loaded.

Comment: @thevikas shouldn't you need to decare `whitelist` and `blacklist` sections in your `codeception.yml`? I'm can generate coverage from yii2 basic example without any issue.